# Apache2 restart at boot on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apache2

Please can any one help me with a script to restart apache2 at boot on ubuntu 10.04. I have tried so many tutorials but never worked and
I tried crontab -e but is there any other way? because it only restart after boot. thank you.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 reached end of live on 2015-04-30 and is not supported any more. Please upgrade to a more recent version, e.g. 12.04

Comment: Do not repost this question either after upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you want some delay time before restarting apache2.
If so, add this to crontab:

```
# On boot wait 20 seconds and restart apache2 service
@reboot sleep 20 && service apache2 restart
```

Comment: yes please that is what I meant, I will try it an give you the feed back. thank you for your reply. I am grateful

Comment: Please I have just applied your answer and it worked perfectly.